# SQL - How to get elements after and before the searched one?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I want to query my table and specify some offset to get rows before and after my found one.

E.g. getting this result set (Specifying offset of 2):

- data 1
- data 2 --> offset: 2 --> so this row is added to my result set as well
- data 3 --> offset: 2 --> so this row is added to my result set as well
- data 4 --> this row is meeting my query condition
- data 5 --> offset: 2 --> so this row is added to my result set as well
- data 6 --> offset: 2 --> so this row is added to my result set as well
- data 7

I have tried LAG/LEAD but this only gives me the possibility to get one column of the next row, I would need a feature which basically adds the offset rows to the result set as well.

**Edit:**
My sample data looks like this:
I got data which stores a cardboard_number, timestamp (says when the cardboard was scanned) and a productionline_number. So basically in my table I have following Columns:

- ID (auto-increment, int)
- Cardboard_Number (varchar)
- DateTime (datetime)
- ProductionLine_Number (int)

Basically, I want to search for a Cardboard_Number, and get the specified number of offsets before and after the one.

So to update my preceding example:

- 2 "1234" 2024-03-23 17:01:01 1
- 4 "123" 2024-03-24 17:01:01 1
- 5 "135" 2024-03-25 09:01:01 2
- 7 "234" 2024-03-25 11:01:01 1
- 9 "134" 2024-03-25 13:01:01 2
- 10 "12345" 2024-03-25 14:01:01 1
- 11 "12346" 2024-03-25 17:01:01 2

So, when specifying e.g. offset 1 and searching for Cardboard_Number "134", I want to get the rows with IDs 5, 9 and 11, as I want to know which cardboard_number was scanned before and after my searched one **per ProductionLine_Number**

**Edit 2:**
In some cases, a Cardboard_Number can occur multiple times in one ProductionLine AND occur in other ProductionLines as well.

I have created a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YDgk3QOL) showing some duplicated cardboards. In this fiddle, when searching for 'WDL-005943998-1' (with an offset of e.g. 1), I would expect IDs 2, 4, 5, 6, 7 from Line1 as result and IDs 9, 10, 11, 12 from Line2, ultimately resulting in a result set of 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12.

To conclude, the result set should contain all Cardboards with the searched number and additionally the "offset rows" which were scanned before and after the searched Cardboard at the line the Cardboard was used.

Comment: This is very vague. Could you please add some sample input data and the expected result? For example, it's unclear how your data is or should be sorted.

Comment: @JonasMetzler Thank you for your feedback. I updated my question and provided more information on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to sum over a range of rows for this:

```
select id, Cardboard_Number, date_Time, ProductionLine_Number
from (
  select id, Cardboard_Number, date_Time, ProductionLine_Number,
    sum(Cardboard_Number='spL1ml82N4o') over (
      partition by ProductionLine_Number
      order by date_Time, id
      rows between 2 preceding and 2 following
    ) matches
  from table1
) table1_with_matches
where matches
```

This will read the entire table; if that's not good enough and you have a `(Cardboard_Number)` index, you could limit it to only production lines that have the number you are looking for:

```
select id, Cardboard_Number, date_Time, ProductionLine_Number
from (
  select p2.id, p2.Cardboard_Number, p2.date_Time, p2.ProductionLine_Number,
    sum(p2.Cardboard_Number='spL1ml82N4o') over (
      partition by p2.ProductionLine_Number
      order by p2.date_Time, p2.id
      rows between 2 preceding and 2 following
    ) matches
  from table1 p1
  join table1 p2 using (ProductionLine_Number)
  where p1.Cardboard_Number='spL1ml82N4o'
) table1_with_matches
where matches
```

If that's still not good enough, you can also restrict to some time range of the matching row.  How to do that depends on whether a Cardboard_Number can occur more than once for the same ProductionLine_Number.

Comment: I know I did not request it, but do you know how the first query would look like in Oracle?

Comment: @philipp8230 oracle should support the same syntax for the subquery and window, but I think doesn't allow you to sum booleans directly, so you'd do `SUM(CASE p2.Cardboard_Number WHEN 'spL1ml82N4o' THEN 1 END) OVER ...` or something like that.  maybe you also can't treat integers as booleans, so you'd need `WHERE matches > 0`.  don't know of anything else

Comment: I tried with the changes you mentioned, then it worked. Thank a lot!

Comment: Of course, sorry I forgot to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to your problem:

```
SET @offset = 1;
SET @cb_num = 'WDL-005943998-1'; #Replace it with any other Cardboard Number
WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() 
         OVER(PARTITION BY PRODUCTIONLINE_NUMBER ORDER BY date_TIME,id ASC) as RN
  FROM table1
  WHERE PRODUCTIONLINE_NUMBER IN (SELECT 
                             PRODUCTIONLINE_NUMBER 
                             FROM table1 
                             WHERE CARDBOARD_NUMBER = @cb_num)
)
SELECT id, Cardboard_Number
FROM CTE as co
WHERE @offset >= ANY (SELECT ABS(co.RN - ci.RN) 
                           FROM CTE as ci 
                           WHERE CARDBOARD_NUMBER = @cb_num 
                           AND co.PRODUCTIONLINE_NUMBER = ci.PRODUCTIONLINE_NUMBER)
```

dbfiddle link - https://dbfiddle.uk/L9ryjZ3J

Comment: I basically agree with that idea. It would just be safer to use `IN` rather than `=` for conditions like `PRODUCTIONLINE_NUMBER = (SELECT ...)` in case the same cardboard_number can appear in different production lines

Comment: @JonasMetzler Thanks I will do so but philipp8230 has to confirm whether such situation arises or not since if there are more than 1 production line then in that case change in the above query is required at more than one place.

Comment: @philipp8230 Ok no problem I will add that case also.

Comment: @Nishant Gupta Thank you very much! Just for the timeline I post my deleted comment again:
Thank you very much! But i forgot to mention one detail, I'm very sorry. The solution works perfectly if I search for Cardboards which occur only one time in the table. But in some cases, it might be that the Cardboard is scanned multiple times on different ProductionLines. Do you think there's a solution which is covering this case as well?

Comment: @philipp8230 I have updated my solution. Try it now and let me know whether it is working or not.

Comment: @NishantGupta I tried the updated solution. Unfortunately, I get an error "Subquery returns more than 1 row". I think the error occurs in the line starting with `ABS ...`. The error occurs when searching for a Cardboard which is occuring multiple times on one line AND on other lines as well

Comment: @philipp8230 If a cardboard occurs multiple times on one line then what will be the expected output?

Comment: @NishantGupta All Cardboards matching the query + the offset for each Cardboard

Comment: Can you give one example for that one also when same cardboard occurs for multiple times in one production line?

Comment: @NishantGupta The issue occurs when they do not use the whole Cardboard entirely at once. E.g. they use a third of the Cardboard content at one production process. The second third is used on the same line in another production process. The last third might be used on another line on another process. This is usually not the standard case, but it definitely could happen

Comment: Is there any column for production processes as well which are different for same production line?

Comment: @NishantGupta I will provide you with a dbfiddle with some more sample data in a moment

Comment: @NishantGupta https://dbfiddle.uk/-5-R3XjE - I added some data which shows only duplicate cardboards. Unfortunately, we do not have any column other than the productionline_number, but we would be able to add a column if it is needed.

Comment: @NishantGupta The problem with adding an additional column is, that at time of scanning, the workers do not know the number of the production process themselves. They just scan the Cardboard and add it to any running production process

Comment: @NishantGupta Basically, the result set should contain all searched Cardboards and the specified number of "offset rows" which where scanned on the specific production line before and after each found Cardboard.

Comment: @philipp8230 Ok got it Thanks. can you update your question with this info you provided in comments and also tell the expected output for the sample data you provided in the above dbfiddle link.

Comment: @NishantGupta I added the information about the duplicated cardboards in my original post. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: @philipp8230 Updated my solution you can check now. Plus go through sample data once again for ambiguity between columns id and datetime. Please see row having id 5 and 7 they are having exact same datetime but in between them there is one more id i.e. 6.

Comment: @NishantGupta Thank you very very much, you saved my day! I updated my fiddle so the datetimes make sense, thank you for pointing out!

Comment: always better to make order by non-ambiguous; make it `ORDER BY date_Time, id`