# Iterating over C# List and execute a SELECT statement in the database for each element - more efficient way?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have an SQL query exactly as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78224006/sql-how-to-get-elements-after-and-before-the-searched-one). To sum it up, it will read all Carboards specified with an offset. This query is executed on a MariaDB database.
Now, I have my Cardboards (ID, Cardboard_number, DateTime, Production_LineNumber) in my C# ASP.NET program. I have to read all production processes in which each Carboard was used (basically production.start <= cardboard.datetime <= production.end).

The table for the Productions in the Oracle database looks like this (I did not create that table myself and I am not able to change anything because it is used in a production program as well):

- PRODUCTION_NUMBER (NUMBER)
- POSNR (NUMBER)
- DATETIME (TIMESTAMP(6))
- PROCESS_ACTIVE (VARCHAR2(1))
- PRODUCTION_LINE (NUMBER)

The PROCESS_ACTIVE column is used like a flag, when starting a production process a row is inserted with DATETIME=sysdate, PROCESS_ACTIVE = 1 and a stopped one is indicated with sysdate, PROCESS_ACTIVE = 0.

I have created a query which sums up my processes, so I get a Start und End for each PRODUCTION_NUMBER and POSNR:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT PRODUCTION_NUMBER, POSNR, PROCESS_ACTIVE, PRODUCTION_LINE, DATETIME as START, LEAD(DATETIME, 1, SYSDATE) OVER (ORDER BY DATETIME ASC) AS END
    FROM ssq_lauftr
    GROUP BY PRODUCTION_NUMBER, POSNR, PROCESS_ACTIVE, PRODUCTION_LINE, DATETIME
    ORDER BY DATETIME 
)
WHERE PROCESS_ACTIVE = 1
```

I iterate over all Cardboards retrieved from the MariaDB in my C# code and execute this query for **every cardboard** (where *cardboard* is the injected object from my C# loop):

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT PRODUCTION_NUMBER, POSNR, PROCESS_ACTIVE, PRODUCTION_LINE, DATETIME as START, LEAD(DATETIME, 1, SYSDATE) OVER (ORDER BY DATETIME ASC) AS END
    FROM ssq_lauftr
    WHERE PRODUCTION_LINE = cardboard.PRODUCTION_LINENUMBER and DATETIME <= cardboard.DATETIME
    GROUP BY PRODUCTION_NUMBER, POSNR, PROCESS_ACTIVE, PRODUCTION_LINE, DATETIME
    ORDER BY DATETIME 
)
WHERE PROCESS_ACTIVE = 1 AND cardboard.DATETIME <= END
```

which is working quite well with a low number of cardboards.

The problem with this solution is that if I have a lot of Cardboards, the whole function for reading all Productions will take too long. Is there a way (e.g. with PLSQL) to make this process more efficient? The SQL statement above is quite fast, but iterating over the list in C# and adding the results to my ProductionSet is slowing down the application a lot.

**Edit:**
The cardboards are stored in the MariaDB, while the Productions are stored in the Oracle DB.
My current C# code for the described functionality looks like this:

```
Cardboards = [.. _mariaDB.Cardboards.FromSql($@"
    SET @cb_num = {request.Cardboard_Number};
    select *
    from (
        SELECT *,
        sum(Cardboard_Number LIKE CONCAT(@cb_num, '%')) over (
            partition by ProductionLine_Number
            order by timestamp, id
            rows BETWEEN {CardboardOffset} preceding AND {CardboardOffset} following
        ) matches
        from cardboards
    ) cardboards_with_matches
    where matches
")];

HashSet<Production> productionSet = [];

for(int i = 0; i < Cardboards.Count(); i++)
{
    productionSet.UnionWith(_oracleDB.Production.FromSqlRaw($@"
        SELECT * 
        FROM
        (
            SELECT PRODUCTION_NUMBER, POSNR, PROCESS_ACTIVE, PRODUCTION_LINE, DATETIME as START, LEAD(DATETIME, 1, SYSDATE) OVER (ORDER BY DATETIME ASC) AS END
            FROM Productions
            WHERE PRODUCTION_LINE = {Cardboards.ElementAt(i).ProductionLine_Number} and {Cardboards.ElementAt(i).DateTime} <= cardboard.DATETIME
            GROUP BY PRODUCTION_NUMBER, POSNR, PROCESS_ACTIVE, PRODUCTION_LINE, DATETIME
            ORDER BY DATETIME 
        )
        WHERE PROCESS_ACTIVE = 1 AND {Cardboards.ElementAt(i).DateTime} <= END
    "));
}
```

[MariaDB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7sFrE5pU) - Fiddle for Cardboards
[OracleDB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KrPvEEtj) - Fiddle for Productions (not running in fiddle, but running in Oracle SQL developer, I honestly don't know the problem there)

To break it down, basically when the user searches for the Cardboard 'WDL-005943998-1' the expected output would be the data from the whole Cardboard (searched in MariaDB) and the Production with PRODUCTION_NUMBER = 461618, as the DateTime of the Cardboard is between the Start and End of the Production AND the Production was on the same line as the Cardboard was scanned.

Note that there could be the same Production multiple times, but with different timestamps (e.g. production was paused).

Comment: You mention MariaDB throughout the question but you have tagged Oracle (and mention PLSQL in the final paragraph). These are two different RDBMS; which one are you using?

Comment: @MT0 Actually, both. The Cardboards table is stored in the MariaDB, while the Productions are stored in the Oracle DB.

Comment: You could create a database link from Oracle to MariaDB and then directly use the table; rather than trying to read the MariaDB table into C# and then try to inject it into an Oracle query. (The C# Oracle database drivers do not support passing SQL collections - i.e. array data types - and only, for some unknown reason, support passing associative arrays - i.e. map data types. If you want to pass an array of values via C# then you need to pass an associative array and convert it to a collection in the database so you would be better to connect the two databases and do it directly).

Comment: Please [edit] the question an include a [MRE] with the relevant C# code.

Comment: @MT0 Sure, I will update my question. Actually, it would be an option to migrate the Cardboards table to the Oracle DB. Am I right to assume that this would fix my problem because I could use an CURSOR?

Comment: You haven't shared the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data nor what the expected output would be for that sample data. If you have both the tables in the same DB (or both accessible from Oracle via a database link) then I would not use a cursor and loops because that is very inefficient; I would try to use a `JOIN` between the two tables. But working out how to implement that would require knowing more about your data and the expected output.

Comment: Why do you use two different RDBMS?

Comment: Copying the cardboards to Oracle over a heterogeneous db link (via gateway) would enable you to get all the data you need in one SQL execution. That would be the most efficient method. If you can't do that, at least create a temporary table in Oracle and array insert the cardboard keys into it from your C# program. Then do that single SQL that gets the Oracle data joining to the temp table. PL/SQL isn't a solution here, it's avoiding a separate query and round trip for every cardboard that you need, which also allows for other join methods than nested loops for bulk data.

Comment: Also, ensure that you are using bind variables in your query, not string concatenating the values in as literals. You want to eliminate parse time as the primary culprit. It is still likely that with millions of calls your network latency is primarily responsible, but just to be sure parsing isn't adding to the problem. I don't remember much about C# but your code looks like it might be string concatenating and that'd be a problem. Research how to use bind variables.

Comment: @MT0 I updated my question and provided some sample data, I hope this helps.

Comment: @JonasMetzler Honestly, this is during development process only. We plan to migrate the MariaDB database to Oracle as soon as we are starting to going live, perhaps it would have been better to directly develop with an Oracle RDBMS - but we didn't know better.

Comment: @PaulW I appreciate the tip with bind variables, definitely will look into it.

Comment: The Oracle fiddle does not work because Oracle only allows a single statement in each command (which helps to prevent SQL injection attacks) so you cannot have `CREATE`, `INSERT` and `SELECT` in the same command. Move each command to a separate box and it will work.

Comment: @PaulW Just as an additional information to your tip with bind variables, as of the MSDC: "While this syntax may look like regular C# string interpolation, the supplied value is wrapped in a DbParameter and the generated parameter name inserted where the {0} placeholder was specified. This makes FromSql safe from SQL injection attacks, and sends the value efficiently and correctly to the database." - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#passing-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the two tables either: both in the Oracle database; or have the MariaDB database accessible from the Oracle database (i.e. via a database link) then you can find all the relationships between the two tables using the query:

```sql
WITH production_bounds (production_number, posnr, process_active, production_line, start_dt, end_dt) AS (
  SELECT PRODUCTION_NUMBER,
         POSNR,
         PROCESS_ACTIVE,
         PRODUCTION_LINE,
         DATETIME as start_dt,
         LEAD(DATETIME, 1, SYSTIMESTAMP) OVER (
           PARTITION BY production_line
           ORDER BY DATETIME ASC
         ) AS end_dt
  FROM   productions
)
SELECT p.production_number,
       p.posnr,
       p.process_active,
       p.production_line,
       p.start_dt,
       p.end_dt,
       c.id,
       c.cardboard_number
FROM   production_bounds p
       INNER JOIN cardboard c
       ON     p.production_line = c.productionline_number
          AND c.date_time BETWEEN p.start_dt AND p.end_dt
```

Which, for the sample data (with both tables in Oracle):

```sql
CREATE TABLE cardboard
(
    id int,
    Cardboard_Number varchar2(100),
    date_Time TIMESTAMP(0),
    ProductionLine_Number int
);

INSERT INTO cardboard VALUES 
(2,'WDL-005943998-1', TIMESTAMP '2014-08-05 10:03:32', 1),
(4,'spL1ml82N4o',TIMESTAMP '2024-02-29 17:13:54', 1),
(5,'WDL-005943998-1',TIMESTAMP '2024-03-01 09:44:42', 1),
(6,'WDL-005943998-1',TIMESTAMP '2024-03-01 10:34:57', 1),
(7,'950024027237',TIMESTAMP '2024-03-01 10:44:57', 1),
(8,'950024027237',TIMESTAMP '2024-03-01 10:52:57', 1),
(9,'WDL-005943998-1',TIMESTAMP '2024-03-01 13:58:43', 2),
(10,'WDL-005943998-1',TIMESTAMP '2024-03-01 13:58:46', 2),
(11,'spL1ml82N4o',TIMESTAMP '2024-03-01 14:09:43', 2),
(12,'WDL-005943998-1',TIMESTAMP '2024-03-12 15:48:36', 2);

CREATE TABLE Productions
(   
  PRODUCTION_NUMBER NUMBER, 
  POSNR NUMBER, 
  DATETIME  TIMESTAMP(0), 
  PROCESS_ACTIVE VARCHAR2(1),
  PRODUCTION_LINE NUMBER
);

BEGIN
INSERT INTO Productions(PRODUCTION_NUMBER, POSNR, DATETIME, PROCESS_ACTIVE, PRODUCTION_LINE)
  VALUES (461793, 1, TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-04 09:01:41', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '1', 1);
INSERT INTO Productions(PRODUCTION_NUMBER, POSNR, DATETIME, PROCESS_ACTIVE, PRODUCTION_LINE)
  VALUES (461793, 1, TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-04 11:01:41', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '0', 1);
INSERT INTO Productions(PRODUCTION_NUMBER, POSNR, DATETIME, PROCESS_ACTIVE, PRODUCTION_LINE)
  VALUES (461618, 2, TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-05 10:01:41', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '1', 1);
INSERT INTO Productions(PRODUCTION_NUMBER, POSNR, DATETIME, PROCESS_ACTIVE, PRODUCTION_LINE)
  VALUES (461619, 2, TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-05 10:02:46', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '1', 2);
INSERT INTO Productions(PRODUCTION_NUMBER, POSNR, DATETIME, PROCESS_ACTIVE, PRODUCTION_LINE)
  VALUES (461618, 2, TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-05 10:05:09', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '0', 1);
INSERT INTO Productions(PRODUCTION_NUMBER, POSNR, DATETIME, PROCESS_ACTIVE, PRODUCTION_LINE)
  VALUES (461619, 2, TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-05 10:07:46', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '0', 2);
INSERT INTO Productions(PRODUCTION_NUMBER, POSNR, DATETIME, PROCESS_ACTIVE, PRODUCTION_LINE)
  VALUES (461818, 1, TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-14 22:53:12', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '1', 1);
INSERT INTO Productions(PRODUCTION_NUMBER, POSNR, DATETIME, PROCESS_ACTIVE, PRODUCTION_LINE)
  VALUES (461818, 1, TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-14 23:25:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '0', 1);
END;
/
```

Outputs:

| PRODUCTION_NUMBER | POSNR | PROCESS_ACTIVE | PRODUCTION_LINE | START_DT | END_DT | ID | CARDBOARD_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 461618 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2014-08-05 10:01:41. | 2014-08-05 10:05:09.000000 | 2 | WDL-005943998-1 |
| 461818 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2014-08-14 23:25:30. | 2024-03-28 12:53:28.569815 | 4 | spL1ml82N4o |
| 461818 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2014-08-14 23:25:30. | 2024-03-28 12:53:28.569815 | 5 | WDL-005943998-1 |
| 461818 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2014-08-14 23:25:30. | 2024-03-28 12:53:28.569815 | 6 | WDL-005943998-1 |
| 461818 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2014-08-14 23:25:30. | 2024-03-28 12:53:28.569815 | 7 | 950024027237 |
| 461818 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2014-08-14 23:25:30. | 2024-03-28 12:53:28.569815 | 8 | 950024027237 |
| 461619 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 2014-08-05 10:07:46. | 2024-03-28 12:53:28.569815 | 9 | WDL-005943998-1 |
| 461619 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 2014-08-05 10:07:46. | 2024-03-28 12:53:28.569815 | 10 | WDL-005943998-1 |
| 461619 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 2014-08-05 10:07:46. | 2024-03-28 12:53:28.569815 | 11 | spL1ml82N4o |
| 461619 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 2014-08-05 10:07:46. | 2024-03-28 12:53:28.569815 | 12 | WDL-005943998-1 |

If you want to search for active rows with a specific `cardboard_number` then add those filters:

```
WITH production_bounds (production_number, posnr, process_active, production_line, start_dt, end_dt) AS (
  SELECT PRODUCTION_NUMBER,
         POSNR,
         PROCESS_ACTIVE,
         PRODUCTION_LINE,
         DATETIME as start_dt,
         LEAD(DATETIME, 1, SYSTIMESTAMP) OVER (
           PARTITION BY production_line
           ORDER BY DATETIME ASC
         ) AS end_dt
  FROM   productions
)
SELECT p.production_number,
       p.posnr,
       p.process_active,
       p.production_line,
       p.start_dt,
       p.end_dt,
       c.id,
       c.cardboard_number
FROM   production_bounds p
       INNER JOIN cardboard c
       ON     p.production_line = c.productionline_number
          AND c.date_time BETWEEN p.start_dt AND p.end_dt
WHERE  cardboard_number = 'WDL-005943998-1'
AND    process_active = 1
```

Outputs:

| PRODUCTION_NUMBER | POSNR | PROCESS_ACTIVE | PRODUCTION_LINE | START_DT | END_DT | ID | CARDBOARD_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 461618 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2014-08-05 10:01:41. | 2014-08-05 10:05:09.000000 | 2 | WDL-005943998-1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vWnahBrA)

Comment: Sorry to ask, but why does the cardboard have "bounds"? The cardboard has only one timestamp, which should be between the start and the end of the production.